# Boost Spirit x3: parse delimited string

Tags: boost, boost-spirit, eager

I'm writing yet another boring calculator parser with Spirit X3 and I've come to a problem: I've defined 2 literals, "cos" and "cosh", each of which expect to be followed by a number. The rules I've written are:

```
const std::string COS_TAG = "cos";
const std::string COSH_TAG = "cosh";
const auto cos = (COS_TAG > value)[math::cos_solver{}];
const auto cosh = (COSH_TAG > value)[math::cosh_solver{}];
```

(I know semantic actions aren't the preferred way, but I'm lazy).
Now, the problem when parsing "cosh 3.5" is:

```
expectation failure: expecting value here "cosh 3.5"
----------------------------------------------^-----
```

Looks like the parser is eager and consumes the first tag without checking for the other. I've made it work by using the difference operator like this:

```
const std::string COS_TAG = "cos";
const std::string COSH_TAG = "cosh";
const auto cos = ((x3::lit(COS_TAG) - COSH_TAG) > value)[math::cos_solver{}];
const auto cosh = (COSH_TAG > value)[math::cosh_solver{}];
```

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, not delimited strings, rather check for token boundaries.

Qi repository had `distinct` for this and I think I may have glanced upon that in the X3 code base once. Will look for it.

Regardless, for now/older versions/your understanding, here are some ways to achieve it:

- re-order the branches, if you match `cosh` before `cos` you get the behaviour you want because of the greedyness
- make a more general assertion about your identifier:

  ```
  auto kw = [](auto p) {
       return x3::lexeme [ x3::as_parser(p) >> !x3::char_("a-zA-Z0-9_") ];
  };
  ```

  Now instead of `lit(COSH)` you can use `kw(COSH)` and be sure it wouldn't match `coshida`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go with the second approach (which is what I achieved but in a more elegant way), I don't like having to think about order of evaluation when using a declarative syntax.

Comment: Yeah, nobody does, which is why PEGs are not the most popular parser generator paradigm